# Evaluate expression and display results in spacemacs

Tags: clojurescript, spacemacs, cider

Recently started playing with Clojurescript in Spacemacs(emacs 26.1). I am using figwheel, I usually make a change in the *.cljs file and then test the results in the function in the REPL. I recently watched a video where someone evaluated the function in the file without having to go to the REPL.
I tried to do the same using cider in spacemacs, The problem is it evaluates but does not display the results.

Below snippet is from config in my project.clj

```
:profiles {:dev {:source-paths ["src" "env/dev/clj"]
                   :dependencies [[binaryage/devtools "0.9.10"]
                                  [figwheel-sidecar "0.5.16"]
                                  [nrepl "0.4.4"]
                                  [cider/piggieback "0.3.9"]]}})
```

Snippet from cljs file.

```
(defn tes []
  (inc 1234))

(prn (tes))
(tes)
```

I tried evaluating `(tes)` and `(prn (tes))`, it evaluates but does not print anything in the echo area.
I have cider setup in spacemacs and cider REPL running during the execution. Executing the function in cider REPL by navigating to the namespace works.

Is there anything I am missing here in order to get it working in terms of setup.

Answer (score 0):

You probaly need cider-nrepl.Put the following in your ~/.lein/profiles.clj file.

```
{:repl {:plugins [[cider/cider-nrepl "0.18.0"]]}}
```